# Easy to maintain ways that helps code readability in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coding-style

Say we start with a base class that states if an object is valid or not (included one interface and two child classes for discussion purpose), like:

```
interface IValid
{
    bool IsValid();
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IValid
{
    public bool Validity { get; protected set; } = true;

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return this.Validity;
    }
}

public class ChildOfTrue : BaseClass
{
    public ChildOfTrue() => this.Validity = true;
}

public class ChildOfFalse : BaseClass
{
    public ChildOfFalse() => this.Validity = false;
}
```

Attempt #1 - null check is implementer's responsibility:

(My thoughts: null check, it's everywhere...)

```
public class TestCase
{
    public TestCase()
    {
        List<BaseClass> testSubjects = new List<BaseClass>
        {
            new ChildOfTrue(),
            new ChildOfFalse(),
            null
        };
        foreach (var testSubject in testSubjects)
        {
            if (testSubject != null && testSubject.IsValid())
            {
                /* Perform tests. */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt #2 - introduce extension:

(My thoughts: I will need to either remove IsValid() from the BaseClass - which creates another problem with the IValid implementation, or change the extension method name to something like IsNotNullAndValid() - which I can call IsValid() instead of checking the property... At least it's going to look a bit more elegant in the end.)

```
public static class BaseClassExtensionHelper
{
    public static bool IsValid(this BaseClass o)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(o, null)) return false;
        return o.Validity;
    }

    public static bool IsNotNullAndValid(this BaseClass o)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(o, null)) return false;
        return o.IsValid();
    }
}
```

Attempt #3 - introduce helper class instead of extension:

(My thoughts: while I can have the best of both choices - calling IsValid() and still name the method IsValid() - from extension, it's not going to look friendly at all - especially if someone wants to chain the method and the method is a conversion.)

```
if (BaseClassExtensionHelper.IsValid(testSubject)) { /* Perform tests. */ }
```

While beauty is in the eye of the beholder, any suggestion to how you would do it for code maintenance + readability and why? (Please give code example as it helps, a lot.)

Thanks!

Comment: Is testcase a unittest? If so Split them in 2 unittests for ChildOfTrue and ChildOfFalse separately. That avoids the complexity

Comment: @Batavia TestCase class is not for unit testing, but an example that shows how to check each object's validity by calling IsValid(). (Which, in the attempt #1, additional null check is required.)

Comment: What’s wrong with using an `abstract` method in your base class that forces every child to implement `IsValid`?

Comment: so why not use (in the foreach) testsubjects.Where (x => x != null). Also i would argue that testSubjects shouldn't contain null elements in the first place if at all possible (exactly to sidestep a lot of the issues you run into now)

Comment: @RubberDuck That's actually how I started - but soon I got worried to forgot to run null check against IValid/BaseClass object before calling IsValid() - so I thought, hey, I can incorporate null check with an extension... But now I am having more doubts.

Comment: @Batavia Sometimes null object just, "comes"? (I am not sure if it is a good practice, but I actually returns null object from factory should the object cannot be built.) So I ended up doing null checks either at start of, or before calling any method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR**
>   You are only responsible to null-check your **encapsulated** logic (= hidden from an external caller). All other information is (by elimination) supplied by the external caller and therefore not your responsibility to null-check (it is the external caller's responsibility).

---

```
public class ChildOfTrue : BaseClass
{
    public ChildOfTrue() => this.Validity = true;
}

public class ChildOfFalse : BaseClass
{
    public ChildOfFalse() => this.Validity = false;
}
```

This is not good practice. Derived classes are created when they introduce *structural differences* from their base class. What you're doing is simply changing a value. This is no different from doing things like:

```
public class John : Person
{
    public John() => this.Name = "John";
}

public class Five : MyNumber
{
    public Five() : base(5) {}
}
```

However, it's possible that your example class is oversimplified for the purpose of example. Regardless, I do question your intention to override a boolean property's value based on some derived classes.

---

```
public bool IsValid()
{
    return this.Validity;
}
```

I don't see the point of this method. It's nothing more than a property accessor.

Why not add the property to the interface? The method has no added value anyway.

```
public IValid IValidity
{
    bool Validity { get; }
}
```

---

> Attempt #2 - introduce extension:

If it's to avoid `null` issues, I can tell you that it's not going to help. Extension methods are matched on variable type (`BaseClass`). Even if your `BaseClass` variable is null, you will still be able to compile and run this.

Yes, you can technically wrap a null check in this method. But your solution is probably going to have more than one class. All classes are nullable, so the problem exists for all classes.

Your current approach would lead you to have to make a similar null-wrapping check for every method that exists in every class that exists. Or, at the very least, for every method or property that is the implementation of an interface.

But since this applies to every class, even if it doesn't have an interface, you should really be doing this on `object` level. Oh wait, but then you can't actually wrap your class-specific methods anymore!

**Trying to create a wrapper method for every public method/property for every class/interface is an exercise in futility, will not lead to cleaner code, and is going to be maintenance hell when you get to a sizeable codebase.**

---

> Attempt #3 - introduce helper class instead of extension:

Extension methods are really just helper methods with a nicer syntax. There is no technical difference between #2 and #3.

---

**Summarization**

What you're trying to do here is go around the intention of the language. Consider this simple variable:

```
BaseClass myObj = new BaseClass();
```

It's important here to distnguish the inside (`BaseClass` methods and properties, what we call "encapsulated logic") from the outside (the client code that declared this variable). This distinction is important, because **`null` exclusively lives on the outside**.

An object cannot know if it's null. By definition, if this object exists, it's not null.

This is like trying to think "what would I be thinking if I didn't exist?". You wouldn't be. That's the entire point of defining "not existing".

The absence of something can only be detected by an outside party that observes the object (or lack thereof). An object cannot detect its own absence, since being able to check for an absence inherently requires an object to exist in the first place. The premise defeats the intention.

**Attempt #1 is correct.** However, there are syntactical improvement to be made that create cleaner code:

```
foreach (var testSubject in testSubjects)
{
    if (testSubject?.IsValid() ?? false)
    {
        /* Perform tests. */
    }
}
```

***Sidenote:** you can also do `testSubject?.IsValid() == true` instead. However, I find that `== true` SEEMS more redundant than it is. `?? false` clearly communicates to the developer who reads the code that it's written to handle cases of `null`.*

or, as an alternative approach:

```
foreach (var testSubject in testSubjects.Where(ts => ts != null))
{
    if (testSubject.IsValid())
    {
        /* Perform tests. */
    }
}
```

or, my preferred option: **not checking for null** (in certain situations).

In your example code, you willfully introduced `null`. In my opinion, the code should blow up in your face: you introduced nonsensical data.

Similarly, if this is a method which receives a list of objects from an external caller, that external caller gave invalid input and therefore needs to be made aware of that.

To summarize the intention of choosing to ignore null checks:

**When the giver of input and the receiver of null reference exceptions is the same party, the exception can be considered good feedback.**  More casually, I call this "shit goes in, shit comes out, no big deal".

For example:

```
public string GetNameOfPerson(Person p) => return p.Name;
```

You supplied `null` to this method, which is obviously going to ensure that this method can't do what you ask it to do. You deserve the exception.

However, if the giver of input is different from the receiver of the NRE, that does mean you need to handle the null. For example:

```
public string GetNameOfPerson(int personId)
{
    var person = myDatabase.GetPerson(personId);

    return person.Name; //possible null reference
}
```

The external caller supplied an ID. He cannot know if the underlying database actually has a person or not. Therefore, he does not deserve to receive a null reference exception, as he is not the one who introduced the null.

In other words, you are only responsible to null-check your **encapsulated** logic (= hidden from an external caller). All other information is (by elimination) supplied by the external caller and therefore not your responsibility to null-check.

There are two solution here. Either you give a more sensical exception:

```
public string GetNameOfPerson(int personId)
{
    var person = myDatabase.GetPerson(personId);

    if(person == null) throw new Exception("Person could not be found.");

    return person.Name; //possible null reference
}
```

Or you return a default value:

```
public string GetNameOfPerson(int personId)
{
    var person = myDatabase.GetPerson(personId);

    return person?.Name ?? "John Doe";
}
```

The correct solution is contextual. Generally speaking, you'd want to avoid throwing exceptions, but there are valid use cases for throwing exceptions.

Comment: Your Attempt #1 examples are syntactically incorrect. `null` and `false` are two distinct values in C# (contrary to C++), `if(null)` is not valid syntax and and does not evaluate to `if(false)`. Building on that, in the alternative the `Where()` is redundant due to the fact the `if (testSubject?.IsValid() == true)` checks both for `null` and `false`.

Comment: @wondra: I missed a `?? false` there, thanks for the catch :) For the second example, the `?` didn't need to be there anymore.

Comment: @wondra: They are also very much distinct in C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator true, it was too strong claim. It should have been that there is implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `NULL` which evaluates as `false` in pretty much all known implementations.

Comment: @Flater Thank you. The logic provided within the summarization section is really helpful. While personally I don't agree with "not checking for null" right now, maybe I will find another case where no null check is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience clearer is to have only one solution to a problem. In attempts 2 and 3 you have IsValid() on object and helper methods which basically do nothing more then call IsValid(). That could confuse developers working with your code.

For shorter null checking you can use [null-conditional operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)`?.`

```
if (testSubject?.IsValid() == true)
{
    /* Perform tests. */
}
```

And wait for [nullable reference types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/) in c# 8

Comment: Why the “Elvis”?

Comment: @DirkBoer: (1) to prevent a NRE from popping up (2) As far as I'm aware, `?:` (the ternary operator) is the Elvis operator, not `?.`

Comment: ahh found it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Answer (score 1):

In a vacuum I would say go with variant #1:
It **is** the caller's responsibility that he or she won't misuse such things, e.g. call functions or access members of `Null` Objects.

Now, there may be instances where you find yourself constantly testing if something is `Null` or not. This is the point where you should stop for some brief reflection: *Why do I need to do all those `Null` checks? Is there some architectural issue, and if so, can I resolve it?* Having to perform constant `Null` checks is a code smell.

If you find that you cannot avoid the `Null` checks for some reason (maybe your 3rd party library vomits lists that contain many `Nulls`) you may be able to encapsulate the issue - create wrapper class which sanitizes the `Nulls` in the Lists (e.g. replacing them, removing them, etc.). If you yourself are the source of `Nulls` you may consider using e.g. a [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead.

In general though, unless you have very good reasons, you should avoid passing `Null` around in your program.

Comment: I am also debating if I should throw exception or continue with silent fail by returning null from the factory. Not to side step from the topic, but, any suggestion on that front?

Comment: @penpen If something in your factory method (or in methods invoked by it) goes wrong and you end up without an object to return, do **not** fail silently and return `Null`. Your `Foo* getFoo()` promises - or at least strongly implies - that it will return a `Foo*`. If it does **not** do so, the user should be make explictely aware of that, and exceptions have been (literally) created for that purpose.